# UTF8 Uppercase displaying incorrectly

Tags: html, database, utf-8, store, uppercase

I have a simple problem, but I do not found any solution for this problem.

I'm using utf8_general_ci encoding in database(MySQL) and in the website is PHP.

In HTML page also using utf-8 as encoding (`<meta charset="utf-8">`).

The problem is that in database I have a word stored which starts with Â, after enconding it appears as Ã the difference is between ^ and ~. Uncoded: Â. Enconded: Ã.

The problem is that in the website appears this �? in the place of the Â but if I change it for lowercase it appears normally. Only uppercase letters appear incorrectly when they have accentuation.

I hope I was clear.

Thanks.

Comment: what dbms? are you using asp? php?

Comment: already edited, I'm using PHP. DB is MySQL. Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you checked the character encoding of your browser?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add lang attribute to the html tag of your web page. For example. Change the `az` to your language code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="az">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
      </head>
      <body>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to set the transfer character encoding for the MySQL link.

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

If this doesn't help, make sure that the server is not overwriting your `<meta charset="utf-8">` via the `Content-Type` HTTP header. You may need to overwrite that as well using

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I will try to do that. Just one question, if other lowercase words with the encoding works why does not the Uppercase?

Comment: This may be that the lowercase accented characters share the same UTF-8 code as the charset you're communicating, but the uppercase ones differ as they are elsewhere in the other encoding. Maybe they included one more character after the lowercase ones and that shifted the whole uppercase part by one.

Comment: It does not work... well the letter now appears but others appear like this: Ã¡. It's not "decoding", If in the DB is Â it appears like Â, if I put Ã it appears Ã. But the encoded ones appear encoded.

Comment: Make sure the php file with static text is saved using UTF-8. If the DB returns a good UTF-8 value, the browsers shows the good UTF-8 value, the characters statically in the php files aren't using UTF-8.

Comment: The php file encoding is UTF8 in preferences. It that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Try to echo some accented characters right after you set the header and see if that comes through. If it doesn't, it may say it's in UTF-8, but that may only apply for newly created php files, not already existing ones. If the accented ones come through ok, I have no clue. Are you sure the file containing those characters is in UTF-8. Please keep in mind that also includes included files like templates and other phps.

Comment: I'm a little confused. :P I echoed some accented characters right after the header ahd they came right. I will check ohter pages for the UTF8 enconding. Are there other simple solution for this encoding thing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. There isn't really a simple solution to this, as character encoding isn't a real thing living in the files. It just maps numbers into familiar symbols (letters for example). If the file you're including has a different encoding, that just means the it transformed the symbols into numbers using a different map, so you can't just set a magic php value to do it for you, as there is nothing it can do.

Comment: Okay... new news :D. If I use the utf8_encode() function of PHP on the variable it appears correctly. Example: $a = "Âbc", utf8_encode($a) returns Â without the function appears �.

Comment: I created a whole new code. New connection to DB and the problem remains. I do not have any other included pages which can not be encoded. The only page using is encoded in UTF8. on MYSQL the collation is utf8_general_ci. On the connection to database the CHARACTER SET is utf8. The uppercase letter (A) with the accent now appears correctly, but the lowercase ones do not. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html), decoding utf-8 as windows1252 or iso-8859-1 produces Ã‚ instead of Â.

and in windows1252 â has code E2 which coincides with its unicode codepoint U+00E2.
that makes me think that some part of your application is correctly decoding the utf-8 string, but failing to encode it correctly.

You should check if your data is consistenly stored in utf-8 in your database, maybe you could select your varchar data as varbinary to be sure (in sqlserver you can convert to binary, in mysql I don't know if it works).

And check the source of your html output to see what bytes are you actually getting.

This is not a proper answer, but was too long for a comment...

Comment: That's a red herring, UTF-8 and Latin-1 and CP1252 are mostly identical in the range 160-255, which includes both lowercase and uppercase accented characters for (some ludicrously constrained sampling of) Western European languages.

Comment: mmm, the codepoints coincide but utf8 uses two bytes (none of them E2) for them so they are not identical.

Comment: Oops, major slip, yes; thanks for the correction. Unicode and Latin-1 are identical in this range but UTF-8 obviously not.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help. I did't quite understand your tip on check if data is consistenly stored in utf-8 in db. In my db i have utf8_general_ci enconding on the fields I'm using and how can I check the html output? Sorry but I'm not used to this enconding "thing"...